# ownCloud sync deleted files

Tags: windows-7, sync, file-recovery, owncloud

Windows 7 Home Premium x64 with ownCloud 1.4.1 sync client and ownCloud 5.0.12 server on Ubuntu 12.04 VPS.

**Sequence of events:**

1. Installation of ownCloud server on the VPS.
2. Configuration, creation of non-admin user. User credentials were the same as previous - basically, today I made transferred VPS from Debian 7 to Ubuntu 12.04. So the address is the same, login credentials are the same, the only changed thing - SSL certificate.
3. Moments after the user was created on the server, ownCloud client on my Windows machine pops up a window to review and accept the security certificate that has been changed.
4. No settings were changed on desktop client, except the fact that I did accept the changed SSL certificate. Previous settings for sync, when I did set it up (for time when I installed Debian 7 ownCloud (that was 5.0.12 as well)), were to sync local folders to the server (NOT clear sync).
5. I get a feeling that something has gone wrong, as ownCloud instantly pops green mark of sync being finished successfully (on the taskbar icon).
6. I instantly open ownCloud, activate pause, and check my ownCloud folder.
7. Everything is empty but two most recently modified files - Unii.odf with date modified 2013.10.11. 3:11 and ts3_ubuntu.txt with date modified 2013.10.12 0:42.
8. New file appeared - .csync_journal, modified by the time the sync had finished - 2013.10.12. 1:47.
9. The rest of my files are gone.

Total size of the deleted data is roughly 7GB, they were on a NTFS disc, secondary disc that has 503GB out of 575GB free. It is a logical partition on HDD in Asus N75SF notebook.

Can I restore at least part of my files? Some of them are important for me - family photos, business documents, education certificates, et cetera.

Download link for .csync_journal in .zip archive - http://rghost.ru/49320648. File hosting at least for me show Russian, if you've got the same, the dark blue/black button with white text 'Скачать' is the download link.

Comment: not sure I follow your description - so you changed the server behind the URL which the client connects to, right? So basically for the client it looked to be the same server but was actually a different one?

Comment: Yes, and after that my windows client did reset all the settings without notifying me, and proceeded with clean sync, wiping out all but two files from my ownCloud folder. I managed to restore deleted files with Puran File Recovery.

Comment: what setting did it reset?

Comment: Instead of syncing local folder to server, a clean sync was initiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you could restore your files! Before doing such major changes it's always a good idea to have a backup handy!

For such a server change to work smoothly, the thing to do would be to turn off the old server, copy all the data to the new server, and only *then* do the DNS switch.

Because the question is: What did you actually expect to happen? I guess you expected the client to automatically determine somehow that you changed the server, and that you actually want to upload the existing data?

The thing is, there is no easy way for the client to determine that you have done such a change. If it's reachable under the same URL, the client assumes it is the same server and will therefore assume you have deleted all your files on the server. That's just how the client perceives it - nothing on server has changed (except the certificate, but that can change on the same server as well), but your files are gone, therefore you must have deleted, ergo, he syncs this deletion.

There were plans to introduce something like a server ID, so that the client can tell if the server the client is currently talking to is still exactly the same as the one he was initially connected to; but that's not implemented (yet?).

Comment: Yeah, I expect it to recognize the server switch and that it will re-use intial settings to upload my data. Lesson learnt.

Answer (score 0):

My friend has sent me link to piece of software called Puran File recovery. It has recovered (with quick scan), most of my files.